# I can not change panel visibility using chosen onchange event in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, panel, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen jQuery plugin to select options. On the base of first selection I want to decide which panel to show or hide. I have two panels, one is
`<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1">`
another is
 `<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel2">`
My chosen onchange event is as below: (this is written in .aspx)

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
('#myId').change(function () {  
                   var abc = $(this).val();  
                   alert('The option with value ' + abc + ' was selected.');  
                   if (abc == "val1") {  
                       alert('Msg1');  
                       document.getElementById("panel2").style.visibility = true;  
                       document.getElementById("panel1").style.visibility = false;  
                       alert('Msg2');  
                   }  
                   else {  
                       alert('Elseloop');  
                       document.getElementById("panel1").style.visibility =true;  
                       document.getElementById("panel2").style.visibility = false;  
                       alert('Elseloop2');  
                   }  
                });  
</script>
```

I also tried `document.getElementById("panel1").style.display ="block";`   but no +ve results, first alert statements in the both loops working properly but panels are not changing their visibility.

while my html is as below:

```
               <select data-placeholder="some text" id="myId" style="width: 350px;" class="chosen-select" tabindex="-1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="val1">Text1</option>
                    <option value="val2">Text2</option>
                    <option value="val3">Text3</option>
                    <option value="val4">Text4</option>
                </select>
```

any suggestion? where I'm making mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call it with a dollar sign and also put it on document ready

Adding $(function(){ before; and }); will do that for you.

If you want to get the Panel id's in your code, you should try getting their proper ids from the HTML of the parsed code

```
<script>
    $(function(){
            $('#myId').change(function () {  
                   var abc = $(this).val();  
                   alert('The option with value ' + abc + ' was selected.');  
                   if (abc == "val1") {  
                       alert('Msg1');  
                       document.getElementById(<%= panel2.ClientID %>).style.visibility = true;  
                       document.getElementById(<%= panel1.ClientID %>).style.visibility = false;  
                       alert('Msg2');  
                   }  
                   else {  
                       alert('Elseloop');  
                       document.getElementById(<%= panel1.ClientID %>).style.visibility =true;  
                       document.getElementById(<%= panel2.ClientID %>).style.visibility = false;  
                       alert('Elseloop2');  
                   }  
                });
             });
</script>
```

Comment: I forgot to type # on my answer to get the full control id. Use $("#<%=Panel1.ClientID%>")

Comment: Actually the questioner is not trying to write a function on Panel change rather than the change handle is on the select which is referred as #myId.

Comment: using $('#myId').change(function () { is wrong? I should not refer 'myId' here?

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel1">
```

and

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel2">
```

are controls `runat="server"` so your id might be rendered like:

```
"ctl00_panel1" and "ctl00_panel2", change your id:
```

To get the full control ID name inside content control use ClientID:

```
 $("#<%=Panel1.ClientID%>").change(function () {
```

Comment: alert statements after "document.getElementById("<%= ctl00_panel1.ClientID %>").style.visibility = true;" are working now, but panel visibility is not changing. I've changed panel Ids as "ctl00_panel1" and "ctl00_panel2"

Comment: Try now using  $("#<%=Panel1.ClientID%>"), I forgot to type #.